# Autowiring in Spring

Tags: spring

I am using `Spring`, i am not using `JSF`, using `ajax` etc.

I have a service

```
@Service(value="mailService")
public class MailService{
//an autowired dao, etc here
}
```

I have a bean, i want this bean have one MailService.

```
//Here i have tried so far individually @Service, @Component, @Controller
public class EmailAgent{

private MailService mailService;



    public MailService getMailService() {
        return mailService;
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setMailService(MailService mailService) {
        this.mailService = mailService;
    }

}
```

I have below in applicationContext.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="mypack.containing.emailagent.path.too" />
<context:annotation-config/>
```

mailService in EmailAgent is null on calling one EmailAgent method.

I request some advise, and i want to understand why i do not get any exception during server starting up, like, "i could not autowire mailService". Awhile ago i was using `JSF` and i was be able to see such warning while server start up.

PROBLEM IS SPECIFIED, HOW TO SOLVE

i was generating ea with `EmailAgent ea=new EmailAgent();`
It is my sillyness but,
when i try to get one context like:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext cont=new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:applicationContext.xml");
                  mailService=()cont.getBean("mailService");
```

i am faced with the problem non unique cache etc, problems about generating one more context.
So how can i "get" context, preventing "generating" one more?

SOLVED

I added

```
<bean class="email.EmailService" id="emailService"> 
  <dwr:remote javascript="emailService"> 
    <dwr:include method="sendMail"/>
    <dwr:include method="readAllMails"/>
    <dwr:include method="removeMailsById"/> 
  </dwr:remote> 
</bean>
```

to dwr.xml and deleted annotation from emailService about dwr.

dwr s and spring s annotations were really conflicting as i can see.

Thanks to @NimChimpsky for idea on detecting the problem.

Comment: how are you instantiatiing mailagent ? Its needs to be managed by spring itself too

Comment: @NimChimpsky thanks very much. It is the point. I edited my question.

Comment: this [Reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.3/reference/beans.html#beans-annotation-config)  may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need another context, unless you are integration testing.

Where is emailagent being used ? Just inject it as normal there.  As you do with mailservice.

You can annotate it with Component or Service, both are appropriate.

Comment: I am using dwr and it has some annotations on same class definition, and annotations are confilicting thus, is there a way to get the bean inline from "existing" context?

Comment: annoations are conflicting ? They don't conflict - just reference the one you want to use.